# Подскажите, как сделать горячую клавишу для выключения скрипта

Tags: python

Подскажите, как сделать горячую клавишу для выключения скрипта

Например, вот рабочий скрипт

```
while True:
    zadacha1()
    zadacha2()
    zadacha3()
    zadacha4()
```

и вот надо как то сделать, чтобы, например, в любое время и в любой функции выполнения скрипта сработала клавиша например F5 что бы скрипт выключится и по возможности еще добавить клавишу F6 пауза

Answer (score 0):

На основе вашей задачи я реализовал воспроизводимый пример. Здесь мы реализуем две глобальные переменные `paused` и `exit_loop`, далее мы создаём для них функции, которые позже назначим как горячие клавиши через модуль `keyboard`, для проверки я реализовал метод `zadacha1()` которая просто возвращает отметку от времени, код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import keyboard
import datetime
import time

def zadacha1():
    #print hello with date and time now
    time.sleep(1)
    print("отметка времени: ", datetime.datetime.now())

paused = False
exit_loop = False

def pause_loop():
    global paused
    paused = not paused
    if paused:
        print("\npaused = True\n")
    else:
        print("\npaused = False\n")

def exit_program():
    global exit_loop
    exit_loop = True
    print("\nexit_loop = True\n")        

# Устанавливаем сочетание клавиш для паузы
keyboard.add_hotkey('f5', pause_loop)
keyboard.add_hotkey('f6', exit_program)

while True:
    if not paused:
        # Ваш код для выполнения задачи
        zadacha1()
        if exit_loop:
            print('\nПрограмма завершена\n')
            break
```

Результат:

```
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:46.483409
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:47.484627
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:48.485523
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:49.485673
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:50.485943

paused = True

отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:51.486116

paused = False

отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:56.388918
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:57.389715
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:58.390017
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:56:59.390176
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:57:00.391006
отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:57:01.391129

exit_loop = True

отметка времени:  2023-06-13 08:57:02.391734

Программа завершена
```

Сначала мы нажали на клавишу `f6` воспроизведя паузу, учитывайте что после нажатия инструкция будет воспроизведена последний раз. Далее мы нажимаем `f5` для завершения программы путём вызова `break`, после нажатия так же цикл будет воспроизведен один раз.

Comment: ага спасибо работает!!!

Comment: только вот самой остановки и паузы нету((( я в питоне еще новичек(

Comment: вопрос банальный, а через какую IDE работайте?

Comment: Для собственного примера я работал через VSCode, там `f5` и `f6` зарезервированы для дебага и запуска программы

Comment: Я переименовал для вас в примере собственном, но сам я пользоваться `ctrl+space` и `ctrl+q`

Comment: просто я нажимаю  F6 и программа не стопиться...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uT2VO6E странно, у меня работает...

Comment: В сообщении выше я использовать PowerShell

Comment: https://ibb.co/xJPHx26    вот так у меня,
вот код https://ibb.co/yYJt56m

Comment: не вижу в вашем `while True` блоке проверки по переменным `paused` и `exit_loop`

Comment: ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО взгляните на то что происходит внутри моего кода в блоке `while True`

Comment: прошу прощение))) мое упущение) спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: @YesNoUs если вас устраивает данный ответ, пометьте его как **верный**, используя кнопку галочки под стрелочками слева ответа

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
import keyboard
while True:
    if(keyboard.is_pressed('f5'):
        sys.exit(0)
    if(keyboard.is_pressed('f6'):
        keyboard.wait('f6')
    zadacha1()
    zadacha2()
    zadacha3()
    zadacha4()
```

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: @Yes: так работает?

Comment: так это как?...